# jQuery checkbox SUM values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with my code. It wont SUM all values of checkboxes. What is the problem here?

I have tried all the ways, but it wont display me anything.

### HTML

```
<div id='vizitkarte'>
    <h2>Vizītkarte</h2>

    <input id='cheackbox_pam_viz' type="checkbox" value="189.95" name="choise" /> <a id='cena_viz' title="189,95 Ls" value="189.95" name="choise" class="cena"></a> 
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" name="choise" /> <a class='popup' rel="popup1"></a><a title="9,95 Ls" value="9.95" name="choise" class="cena"></a>

</div>
<div> <span id="span"></span>
User total usage: <span id="usertotal"> </span>
```

### JavaScript

```
function displayVals() {
      calcUsage();
      var singleValues = $("#more").val();         
      $("#span").html("<b>more addons:</b> " + 
                  singleValues + ' EUR');
}
var $cbs = $('input[name="choise"]');
function calcUsage() {
    var total = $("#more").val();
    $cbs.each(function() {
        if (this.checked)
            total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(this.value);
    });
    $("#usertotal").text(total + ' EUR');
}

    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();
//For  checkboxes

$cbs.click(calcUsage);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2nTB/)

Comment: first of all use jquerry version on the left hand side panel

Comment: I have done this, but it gives me error. I will add that more options.

Comment: your code not understandable please tell me what actually you want to do?

Comment: I want to SUM all values from checked checkboxes.

Comment: You are selecting `$("#more")` but you do not have any `id="more"` in your HTML...

Comment: I have now updated it. It shows me NaN when I check the second box. Why?

Comment: There are so many problems with both your HTML and JQuery it's hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: As I said, I want to SUM all checked boxes in another text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do then this "works". However...I am not aware what is supposed to be selected with `$("#more").val()` as there is not any HTML element with that ID. So...I made that 0.

HTML

```
<div id='vizitkarte'><h2>Vizītkarte</h2>
    <input id='cheackbox_pam_viz' class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="189.95" name="choise" />
    <a  id='cena_viz' title="189,95 Ls" value="189.95" name="choise" class="cena"></a>  
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="189.95" name="choise" /> 
    <a class='popup' rel="popup1"></a><a title="9,95 Ls" value="9.95" name="choise" class="cena"></a>
</div>
<div> <span id="span"></span>
User total usage: <span id="usertotal"> </span>
```

JQuery

```
function displayVals() {
      calcUsage();
      var singleValues = 0; //$("#more").val();         
      $("#span").html("<b>more addons:</b> " + 
                  singleValues + ' EUR<br>');
}
var $cbs = $('.checkbox');
function calcUsage() {
    var total = 0; //$("#more").val();
    $cbs.each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            total = parseInt(total) + parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#usertotal").text(total + ' EUR');
}

    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();
//For  checkboxes

$cbs.click(function() {
    calcUsage();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G2nTB/18/

Comment: Thanks, that was i wanted to get. :)

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it's what you wanted. Good luck the rest of the way!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/G2nTB/6/

HTML

```
<div id='vizitkarte'>
 <h2>Vizītkarte</h2>
<input type="checkbox" value="189.95" name="choise">189,95</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="9.95" name="choise">9,95</input>
</div>

<div>User total usage: <span id="usertotal"> </span>
```

Javascript

```
function displayVals()
{
  calcUsage();
  var singleValues = $("#more").val();         
  $("#span").html("<b>more addons:</b> " +  singleValues + ' EUR');
}
var $cbs = $('input[name="choise"]');
function calcUsage()
{
var total = 0;

$cbs.each(function() {
    if (this.checked)
    {
        total += parseInt(this.value);

    }

});
$("#usertotal").text(total + ' EUR');
}

$("select").change(displayVals);
displayVals();

//For  checkboxes 
$cbs.click(calcUsage);
```